# Rename file using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have files whose filenames are in format ddmmyyyyTEXT.txt

I want to rename all the files to yyyy-mm-dd-TEXT.txt

Here, TEXT is some arbitrary text.

What sed expression I should use ??

Comment: Take a look at `rename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FILE="23022014hello world.txt"
mv "$FILE" "$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\3-\2-\1-\4/')"
```

It cuts the first 2 numbers, second 2 numbers, next 4 numbers and remaining characters separately and arranges according to your requirement